# Write Callback Result to Page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, callback

I have been looking for hours trying to figure out how to write the result of my callback to my webpage. It is a rather specific problem but no solution I have ran across actually works. Here are the details:

**Psuedo Code: (ideally)**

1. User interacts with webpage (in this case, changing the bounds
   within a google map).
2. Upon bounds_changed, javascript grabs the
   bounds and sends them via a jquery callback in the JSON format to my
   C# code.
3. The C# code processes the bounds and returns the searchResults in the form of JSON to webpage to be manipulated by javascript.

*The second part of step 3 is the trouble spot (everything else works). I cannot seem to actually write the result dynamically on completion of the callback.*

**Here is the relevant code:**

Send message from client to server: (this works but just including it for completeness)

```
function toServer(data) {
    var dataPackage = data + "~";
    jQuery('form').each(function () {
        document.getElementById('payload').value = JSON.stringify({ sendData: dataPackage });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: window.location.href.toString(),
            data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("callback compelete");
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("callback Error");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Server Code on page load: (note this does not work [the writing of the `searchResults` that is])

```
        public Map_ResultsViewer_Beta(...)
        {
            ...

            //holds actions from page
            string payload = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["payload"] ?? String.Empty;

            // See if there were hidden requests
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(payload))
            {
                //temp: process the request //2do: make this dynamic
                string temp_AggregationId = CurrentMode.Aggregation;
                string[] temp_AggregationList = temp_AggregationId.Split(' ');
                Perform_Aggregation_Search(temp_AggregationList, true, Tracer);

                //NOTHING BELOW THIS REALLY WORKS, ignore the the 'placeholder' method of displaying the results, it was just one attempt.

                #region 

                // Start to build the response
                StringBuilder mapSearchBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                PlaceHolder MainPlaceHolder = new PlaceHolder();

                mapSearchBuilder.AppendLine("  ");
                mapSearchBuilder.AppendLine("     <script type=\"text/javascript\"> ");
                mapSearchBuilder.AppendLine("     function processCallbackResult(){ ");

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Session["SearchResultsJSON"].ToString()))
                {
                    mapSearchBuilder.AppendLine("     var searchResults=" + HttpContext.Current.Session["SearchResultsJSON"] + ";");
                }
                else
                {
                    mapSearchBuilder.AppendLine("     var searchResults; ");
                }

                mapSearchBuilder.AppendLine("     } ");
                mapSearchBuilder.AppendLine("     </script> ");
                mapSearchBuilder.AppendLine("  ");

                // Add this to the page
                Literal writeData = new Literal { Text = mapSearchBuilder.ToString() };
                MainPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(writeData);

                #endregion

            }
            else
            {
                //string temp_AggregationId = CurrentMode.Aggregation;
                //string[] temp_AggregationList = temp_AggregationId.Split(' ');
                //Perform_Aggregation_Search(temp_AggregationList, true, Tracer);
                HttpContext.Current.Session["SearchResultsJSON"] = "";
            }

        }
```

Actually performing the search: (this works, just putting it here for completeness)

```
        public void Perform_Aggregation_Search(...)
        {
            //search the database for all items in all of the provided aggregations and merge them into one datatable
            List<DataTable> temp_Tables = new List<DataTable>();
            DataTable searchResults = new DataTable();
            foreach (string aggregationId in aggregationIds)
            {
                temp_Tables.Add(Database.Get_All_Coordinate_Points_By_Aggregation(aggregationId, Tracer));
            }
            foreach (DataTable temp_Table in temp_Tables)
            {
                searchResults.Merge(temp_Table);
            }

            //assign and hold the current search result datatable, from now on we will be using this as the base layer...
            HttpContext.Current.Session["SearchResults"] = searchResults;

            //call json writer with these results
            string searchResultsJSON = Create_JSON_Search_Results_Object(searchResults,Tracer);

            //send json obj to page and tell page to read it (via callback results)
            HttpContext.Current.Session["SearchResultsJSON"] = searchResultsJSON;

        }
```

Code to create the JSON object: (this works, just putting it here for completeness)

```
        public string Create_JSON_Search_Results_Object(...)
        {
            //take the search results from db query (incoming) and parse into JSON
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row = null;
            foreach (DataRow dr in searchResults.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in searchResults.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName.Trim(), dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            //return JSON object
            return serializer.Serialize(rows);
        }
```

Did I miss anything? What am I doing wrong? Can you point me in the write direction?

Once again, the problem is in writing the result of the callback to the page.

Thanks!

Comment: So cant you set values to an element on the DOM in your `success` part of the jquery call?

Comment: No. My understanding is that the result within the jquery call is not the actual result from my C# code (how can it be, I'm not explicitly returning a result -am I?). I've tried outputing the result to firebug and searching for my JSON but its not there...

Comment: Is the result you are expecting on your client side from `Create_JSON_Search_Results_Object()`?

Comment: I do not know. I am not sure how it all works to be honest. I visualize a callback to be where you are basically just calling a server-side method and that method has a return value. Apparently, I'm mistaken...

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually do something with the JSON in your `success` method of you ajax post.

You could use JQuery to target a DOM node like this:

```
$('.example').html(result);
```

Comment: I am attempting this... I do not fully understand what the result is. More specifically, how is it derived. In my mind, it should be the return value of my callback which itself calls (and thus returns) the c# method. My understanding does not seem to be actual way it works...

Comment: the 'result' will be whatever data is on the URL you are posting to. If this returns a page, 'result' will be the markup of this page. If that URL is returning JSON your 'result' will be JSON. Have you put a console log in your success to see what your response is?

Comment: Yeah, this didnt work. I added $('#test_temp').html(result); to the success jquery but all it did was process GET requests to the js files referenced to the page. I assume this is simply writing all of my html that is being returned to the test_temp div. Is there are way to do something like document.getElementById('hiddenDiv_searchResults').value = result.searchResults; where I am plucking only the shall we say altered result from the callback?

Comment: How do I return just the JSON as you say?

Comment: The JavaScript AJAX method you've used will just return whatever that URL returns if you were to visit that URL normally. If you want JSON, you need to make sure that URL is a JSON document. I don't know how to do that, that will be in the C#.
If you're returning HTML, and want to just strip our a subset of that, you'll need to parse the HTML, with something like JQuery.

Comment: I see what you are saying but do not really understand. How can you tell that it will return whatever the the normal url request is?

Comment: It's quite difficult to communicate this way, I recommend you read this: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ and understand what it is your JavaScript is doing. Basically, in the 'url' parameter in your post, your specifying a URL. If you made a POST without AJAX, what would happen? Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry but no this doesnt make sense. I tried several things (adding datatype, removing url, and changing .ajax to .post) but no dice. I do not understand what the js is doing and the api.jquery documentation is not helpful to me.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help then. The only thing I can suggest is try to think about what you would do without JavaScript to see if that helps. I'd really recommend trying to understand what your JS is doing. If you're not sure, I don't think I can offer any advice.

Comment: I've done quite a bit of research and tried countless methods to no avail. As far as I can tell there is no simple way to simple issue a callback to C# via JS and have C# process the request and then write out it's response to the request to the page. If I am mistaken, please tell me why.

Comment: Let's break this down - The first thing you need to do is make you C# page (I'm assuming this is a .aspx page?) outputs the data you want when you post to it. Get that bit working first, then we will discuss the next step.